# Authentication Filter in .NET Core 2.x Web API ? What to use instead

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, windows-authentication, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

We have configured windows authentication in a .NET Core web API project using the below.

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

And windows authentication works, we get the user identity. :-)

However I want to run some additional code on user authentication. In particular a database query/update, possible returning access denied. I would need the Identity from windows authentication as it contains the data needed for the database lookup.

I could add the code to a **ClaimsTransformer** however I don't think that's what the **IClaimsTransformation** interface should be used for, as I'm not going to map any claims.

How can I extend the in built windows authentication with some custom code?

Comment: Why does a custom `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` not cut it?

Comment: I might do that, I was just wondering if I was missing something. As in a recommended best practice thing.

Comment: No it's fine. Just go ahead and implement one. Tkae the user ID or name and verify it against your backend.

Comment: Yep, that's what I've finally gone with and it's working fine. thank's for the tip. :-)